# No module named 'ray.rllib.agents.ppo.ppo_policy'

Tags: python, ray

I have this code:

```py
from copy import deepcopy
import json

import ray
try:
    from ray.rllib.agents.agent import get_agent_class
except ImportError:
    from ray.rllib.agents.registry import get_agent_class
from ray.rllib.agents.ppo.ppo_policy import PPOTFPolicy
from ray import tune
from ray.tune.registry import register_env
from ray.tune import run_experiments
```

I am getting the error:

```
No module named 'ray.rllib.agents.ppo.ppo_policy'
```

I tried:

```
pip install ray;
```

Comment: Please use code block and add more detail in your question. Also please include code section.

Answer (score 0):

I re installed the system and reconfigured the environment to solve this problem